# View large video files with HTML Video Tag

Tags: html, html5-video

I’m new to HTML and I wanted to make a sort of Video player in HTML and CSS as a Start. The videos are >80MB. When I view the page though, the video doesn’t load and the Player is just gray. This is my Code:

`<video src="video.mp4" height="720" controls></video>`

I tried a smaller video and it worked completely fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

For large videos you almost certainly don't want to download the entire video before playing it.

There are several techniques which will allow you start playback while the video is still downloading.

The simplest is usually referred to as progressive download - the client will request the video file in byte ranges from the server.

For this to work the server must support range requests - this may be a configuration option depending on the server.

For mp4 files, the header info, or MOV atom, must be at the start of the video also.

For more sophisticated use cases you may want to look at Adaptive Bit Rate streaming, HLS and DASH but I suspect these may be overkill for you and they typically require a specialised streaming server.